# Why do I get a code sign error when I publish my app on app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing

Yesterday I tried to publish my app but I got an error:

> Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid,
>   or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

This is my log:

> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was
>   invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.
>   (-19011)
>   Executable=/Users/IamMo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jungle_Jumper-frylvnqvacnaoifljuswxrhwloju/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Jungle
>   Jumper.app/Jungle Jumper codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for
>   profile evaluation Illegal entitlement key/value pair:
>   keychain-access-groups, {type =
>   mutable-small, count = 1, values = (  0 : {contents = "5ZT9U8689K.com.RainbowMouth.junglejump"}
>   )} Illegal entitlement key/value pair: application-identifier,
>   5ZT9U8689K.com.RainbowMouth.junglejump AssertMacros:
>   filter_entitlements(entitlements_whitelist, entitlements_requested,
>   allowable_entitlements),  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 932
>    - (null)

Comment: Are you using a deployment certificate for app store submission to sign it? Any of the other types of certs you get from the provisioning portal (such as development or ad-hoc) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate must be a deployment certificate that is specifically designed for the App Store (so Ad-Hoc certificates won't work).  You have to do these steps:

1. Create the deployment certificate in the provisioning portal.  This can only be done by the team agent for the development account.
2. Download the deployment certificate to your machine (or use Xcode 4 to get the certificate).  Be sure it is installed and shows up in the Xcode 4 organizer.
3. Go under Build Settings and change the Code Signing options for the 'release' version to point to this certificate.

If you follow these steps, you shouldn't have a code-signing error (be sure to use the validator before submitting your application as well).

Comment: what is a deployment certificate ? how do create ?

Comment: Read this guide for getting your app ready for distribution: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW21

Comment: i did and now i get this : warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/IamMo/Desktop/Jungle Jumper/build/Distribution-iphoneos/Jungle Jumper.app/Jungle Jumper
AssertMacros: message,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 554
AssertMacros: profile,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 918
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/IamMo/Desktop/Jungle Jumper/build/Distribution-iphoneos/Jungle Jumper.app/embedded.mobileprovision
 - (null)

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your log, add an Entitlements-File to your project. To do this, right click in the left sidebar and click create file. In the appearing view select Code Signing and select the Entitlement. Press save. Next add the name of your Entitlements-File including the suffix (.plist) under the Build Settings of your configuration. (Code Signing Entitlements)

The probably most important thing is to open the Entitlements.plist and change the bool value of the only entry to "NO". That's it.

If you still have any problems, check if you selected your Distribution profile under your Release-Configuration (or which you created). Then try to archive your application und Product -> Archive. And then submit it using the organizer, it's a more powerful method than the Application Loader.

Comment: Some tips because you're new to iPhone Development: Set your deployment target to a much earlier sdk, this makes it possible to download and run your app on elder devices and I suggest you to use Xcode 4...

Comment: Is your Bundle Identifier correct? It needs to be the same as your App ID.